# EMR dyanmodb export failed because of table capacity set to on-demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

After we changed the dynamodb table capacity to on-demand, the data pipeline job to export dynamodb table failed with this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Read throughput should not be less than 1. Read throughput percent: 0.0
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractDynamoDBInputFormat.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:520)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:512)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:394)
```

Any workaround to this issue?

Thanks

--gsu

Comment: As of today, the EMR connector now supports DynamoDB tables set to on-demand billing. https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/pull/88

Comment: Today this is still a problem when using the data pipeline for example. I have to remove the on-demand provisioning in DynamoDB -- after that it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd contact AWS support to confirm, but I was told the EMR DynamoDB connector does not formally support tables using on-demand provisioning yet. So, more than likely you need to switch the table back to provisioned capacity as a workaround.

Edit: As of 23 January 2019, the [EMR connector for DynamoDB supports tables set to on-demand billing](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/pull/88).

Comment: Not the answer I would like to hear. I hope AWS does update the EMR DynamoDB connector to support on-demand provisioning.

Comment: In case someone else also has this problem. There's a bug open in the EMR DynamoDB connector project in GitHub. Hopefully, next release will have the fix.
https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/issues/86

Comment: I'm still getting this issue now, even though they are showing as resolved

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is not resolved, then you might need to change at 3 places:

1. You need to use emr release `emr-5.26.0` to `emr-5.30.0`.
2. Replace `org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDbExport` with `org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBExport`. Notice the change in casing. Similar for DynamoDBImport.
3. If you are using [emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector), then you need to clone its latest version, generate the `emr-ddb-tools` jar by `mvn clean install` and then use the generated jar for `emr-dynamodb-tools` which would be version 4 or higher currently and replace this in your arguments. These should resolve the issue.

Also, there is an issue currently with emr releases 31 or higher if you are using `emr-dynamodb-tools` which shows you error related to some `joda-time` framework. I would restrict to using any releases between `emr-5.26.0` to `emr-5.30.0`.